# Can nc send message from client to server on a udp port?

Tags: networking, netcat, udp

Both client and server are Debian 11

On Server as root:
`nc -ulp 1194`

On Client as root:
`nc -u serverip 1194`

When I type something on client, in theory it should appear on the server right if no firewall is blocking the port 1194? Whatever I type on client, doesn't show up on the server. When I do `nc -vzu serverip 1194` from the client, it says that the port is open. Why isn't the message is showing on the server side?

Comment: Is anything else already listening on UDP/1194? Can you use `tshark` to watch for relevant packets - on server and client? Have you checked for firewall rules, or a firewall between the two systems?

Comment: nc -uz sends a single byte as UDP and checks if it receives an ICMP error as reply: if it receives it will tell closed, if not open. But open just means "no ICMP error". There can be an UDP application listening, or packets dropped due to firewall or routing blackhole.

Comment: nc -uz is kinda useless if firewall is dropping packets. I tried with OpenVPN listening on server and without. In both cases nc shows 1194 open. I don’t have access to the firewall between client and server. I was told by network team that the ports are open bidirectionally. I am just looking from an OS point of view to see if they are open. Haven’t tried tshark. Nothing blocking in iptables.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you use `tshark`/`tcpdump` (or `wireshark` if you prefer the graphical interface) to check (a) that packets are being generated on the client, and (b) that said packets are arriving on the server. For example, `tshark -i {interface} -f 'proto UDP and port 1194'` as root

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your issue with Ubuntu's `netcat-openbsd` v. 1.218 (a fork of the original `netcat`, with added IPv6 support).

The problem (on my machine) is that `nc -ulp 1194` listens on all IPv4 addresses while `nc -u serverip 1194` sends its datagram to the IPv6 address.

Solution: `nc -4 -u serverip 1194` (the `-4` option forces the use of IPv4)

Comment: The `nc` commands for Debian are correct. It was a network firewall issue. I can see nc messages from client to server now.

Comment: Additionally, on my Debian 11 machine, `nc -4 -u serverip 1194` gives an error `nc: invalid option -- '4'
nc -h for help`

Comment: @rocky_alpine You probably don't use `netcat-openbsd` but `netcat-traditional`. `apt install` the former.